# What type of conditions can accept if , while and for in C++?

Tags: c++

Sometimes I see on the internet programs that read from a file like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
string line;
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
  while ( getline (myfile,line) )
  {
    cout << line << '\n';
  }
myfile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
return 0;
}
```

I want to know if `while ( getline (myfile,line) )` means "as long as the text file has lines that haven't been read keep reading them" and if  "while" can accept other conditions that I don't know about.
Also I want to know if there is a method to read a text file character by character not line by line.

Comment: This is pretty basic and should be covered by textbooks and tutorials (`if`, `while`), and yes, you can read a character at a time, but generally that is not the best way to do it.

Comment: Nothing magical going on there OP. It's not that the `while` statement understands what `getline` is doing, it's just that `getline` returns a value that can be interpreted as `true` or `false` by `C`'s conditional statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ you can read a file char by char as given example

```
char oneChar;
fstream fin("file", fstream::in);
while (fin >> noskipws >> oneChar) 
{
    cout << oneChar; 
    // or do desired operation with oneChar
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are correct about the while, it will keep reading until it finds `EOF`, or End-Of-File. While can accept anything that returns true or false, so any function that returns bool (or even numbers, etc) will work.